# Why is my string formatting failing in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, string-formatting

In Java, I can do the following to format a floating point number for display:

```
String output = String.format("%2f" 5.0);
System.out.println(output);
```

In theory, I should be able to do the same thing with this Clojure:

```
(let [output (String/format "%2f" 5.0)]
    (println output))
```

However, when I run the above Clojure snippet in the REPL, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java's `String.format` takes an `Object[]` (or `Object...`), to use `String.format` in Clojure you need to wrap your arguments in an array:

```
(String/format "%2f" (into-array [5.0]))
```

Clojure provides a wrapper for format that's easier to use:

```
(format "%2f" 5.0)
```

Kyle